How do I connect to a ESP32 board using CodeSkool when it is trying to use ws over https? Are there better alternatives?
I am trying to use CodeSkool to help my daughter out with a robotics project since she is used to block programming. I can get everything working on my Arduino IDE. However, CodeSkool requires you install their image and connect before starting development. I install the software and can see the login and successfully login at the ip address. However, when I try to connect to the board in the IDE it just spins. When I look at the logs I see

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.codeskool.cc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://10.0.0.XX/esp32blocks'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

This makes sense as you can't access a non-secure web-socket from an https site, however, this is preventing my from connecting.
Is this app just no longer supported? Do I need to do something fancy to get it to use wss? Is there an alternative block programming IDE I can use that is easier (or even better works with the Arduino IDE?
I have looked around and everything seems to be fairly old and no longer maintained in terms of other IDEs or plugins so I am lost.
